# Attempting to make block elements touch each other in Mailchimp

Tags: block, mailchimp

Even though I set padding to "0" in Mailchimp design areas, my content blocks don't butt up and touch each other, there is a whitespace between the blocks.  I dragged over and inserted a code block, but I don't know what to put in it to make these items touch.  I added a picture of the code block input area.  Can somebody please tell me what code to put in this area?  Thanks so much in advance.  I removed the > so that it would render on the page.  Sorry for being such a newbie with this.

This is in the code box. div class="mcnTextContent" Use your own custom HTML /div

Answer (score 2):

I found this Mailchimp workaround in a Facebook feed:

Use the Code block to build your sections and remove padding and spacing.

Drag a Code block into your layout. Delete the code that is already in there. Copy and paste the code shown below into the block, save and close.

```
<table style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;background-color:#FF0000;" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 10px 18px 9px; line-height: 200%;" valign="top">
        <p class="null" style="font-family: helvetica; font-weight:700; font-size: 35px;text-align:center;color:white">September 2018 Newsletter</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Drag another Code block into your layout, below the block you just created. Delete the code that is already in there. Copy and paste the code shown below into the block, save and close.

```
<table class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:0px;" valign="top">
                <!--[if mso]>
                <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                <![endif]-->
                <!--[if mso]>
                <td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
                <![endif]-->
                <table style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%; background-color:#c0c0c0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                    <tbody><tr>                
                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;" valign="top">
            <h1 style="text-align:center">It's time to design your email.</h1>
            <p>Now that you've selected a template, you'll define the layout of your email and give your content a place to live by adding, rearranging, and deleting content blocks.</p>
            <p>By using image with caption blocks in multi-column templates, you can create a product grid that works perfectly for e-commerce.</p>
            <p>If you need a bit of inspiration, you can <a class="mc-template-link" href="http://inspiration.mailchimp.com">see what other MailChimp users are doing</a>, or <a class="mc-template-link" href="http://mailchimp.com/resources/email-design-guide/">learn about email design</a> and blaze your own trail.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <!--[if mso]>
                </td>
                <![endif]-->

                <!--[if mso]>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Original Facebook feed](https://www.facebook.com/mailchimp/posts/how-can-we-change-the-margins-or-padding-of-a-text-block-as-ours-is-set-up-there/10153705027400777/) - click on comments to see original feed